# How to generate a Fluent UI theme with in the library?

Tags: reactjs, office-ui-fabric, fluent-ui, fluentui-react

I was creating a react application with Fluent UI - React, I want something like each user can pick a Primary Color, Text Color, and Background Color when they sign up and their app will be in that theme like the same way done in the [Theming Designer](https://fluentuipr.z22.web.core.windows.net/heads/master/theming-designer/index.html)

The theming designer gives me the following output.

```
const appTheme: PartialTheme = createTheme({
  palette: {
    themePrimary: "#ff5460",
    themeLighterAlt: "#0a0304",
    themeLighter: "#290d0f",
    themeLight: "#4d191d",
    themeTertiary: "#993239",
    themeSecondary: "#e04a54",
    themeDarkAlt: "#ff656f",
    themeDark: "#ff7d86",
    themeDarker: "#ff9fa6",
    neutralLighterAlt: "#000000",
    neutralLighter: "#000000",
    neutralLight: "#000000",
    neutralQuaternaryAlt: "#000000",
    neutralQuaternary: "#000000",
    neutralTertiaryAlt: "#000000",
    neutralTertiary: "#c8c8c8",
    neutralSecondary: "#d0d0d0",
    neutralPrimaryAlt: "#dadada",
    neutralPrimary: "#ffffff",
    neutralDark: "#f4f4f4",
    black: "#f8f8f8",
    white: "#000000",
  },
});
```

Is there a function that generates theme in Fluent UI in which I just want to provide Primary Color, Text Color, and Background Color and it gives the entire theme so that I can add it to the Theme Provider component.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Resolved it by creating a function,

```
import {
  BaseSlots,
  createTheme,
  getColorFromString,
  isDark,
  Theme,
  ThemeGenerator,
  themeRulesStandardCreator,
} from "@fluentui/react";

const generateTheme = (
  primaryColor: string,
  textColor: string,
  backgroundColor: string
): Theme => {
  const themeRules = themeRulesStandardCreator();
  const colors = {
    pColor: getColorFromString(primaryColor)!,
    tColor: getColorFromString(textColor)!,
    bColor: getColorFromString(backgroundColor)!,
  };

  const currentIsDark = isDark(
    themeRules[BaseSlots[BaseSlots.backgroundColor]].color!
  );

  ThemeGenerator.insureSlots(themeRules, currentIsDark);
  ThemeGenerator.setSlot(
    themeRules[BaseSlots[BaseSlots.primaryColor]],
    colors.pColor,
    currentIsDark,
    true,
    true
  );
  ThemeGenerator.setSlot(
    themeRules[BaseSlots[BaseSlots.foregroundColor]],
    colors.tColor,
    currentIsDark,
    true,
    true
  );
  ThemeGenerator.setSlot(
    themeRules[BaseSlots[BaseSlots.backgroundColor]],
    colors.bColor,
    currentIsDark,
    true,
    true
  );

  const themeAsJson: {
    [key: string]: string;
  } = ThemeGenerator.getThemeAsJson(themeRules);

  const finalTheme = createTheme({
    ...{ palette: themeAsJson },
    isInverted: currentIsDark,
  });

  return finalTheme;
};

export default generateTheme;
```

Actually, this must be part of Fluent UI

Answer (score 1):

The code given in the answer by Aravid Jaimon did produce incomplete results for me.

This is the solution I came up with for this purposes. It is mostly condensed from the [ThemingDesigner.tsx source code](https://github.com/microsoft/fluentui/blob/master/apps/theming-designer/src/components/ThemingDesigner.tsx):

```js
import {
    BaseSlots,
    createTheme,
    getColorFromString,
    isDark,
    IThemeRules,
    ThemeGenerator,
    themeRulesStandardCreator,
} from '@fluentui/react';

function generateTheme(
    {
        primaryColor, textColor, backgroundColor,
    }: {
        primaryColor: string, textColor: string, backgroundColor: string,
    },
) {
    const themeRules = themeRulesStandardCreator();
    const colors = {
        primaryColor: getColorFromString(primaryColor)!,
        textColor: getColorFromString(textColor)!,
        backgroundColor: getColorFromString(backgroundColor)!,
    };

    const isCustomization = false;
    const overwriteCustomColor = true;

    ThemeGenerator.setSlot(
        themeRules[BaseSlots[BaseSlots.backgroundColor]],
        colors.backgroundColor,
        undefined,
        isCustomization,
        overwriteCustomColor,
    );

    const currentIsDark = isDark(themeRules[BaseSlots[BaseSlots.backgroundColor]].color!);

    ThemeGenerator.setSlot(
        themeRules[BaseSlots[BaseSlots.primaryColor]],
        colors.primaryColor,
        currentIsDark,
        isCustomization,
        overwriteCustomColor,
    );
    ThemeGenerator.setSlot(
        themeRules[BaseSlots[BaseSlots.foregroundColor]],
        colors.textColor,
        currentIsDark,
        isCustomization,
        overwriteCustomColor,
    );

    // strip out the unnecessary shade slots from the final output theme
    const abridgedTheme: IThemeRules = Object.entries(themeRules).reduce(
        (acc, [ruleName, ruleValue]) => (
            (
                ruleName.indexOf('ColorShade') === -1
                && ruleName !== 'primaryColor'
                && ruleName !== 'backgroundColor'
                && ruleName !== 'foregroundColor'
                && ruleName.indexOf('body') === -1
            )
                ? {
                    ...acc,
                    [ruleName]: ruleValue,
                }
                : acc
        ),
        {} as IThemeRules,
    );

    return createTheme({ palette: ThemeGenerator.getThemeAsJson(abridgedTheme) });
}
```